# Changing the button color of Alert box in Sencha

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I change the Alert box button color using Sencha Touch 2? It depends on the base-color which is black in my case. And the buttons look like labels as the whole alert box is in black. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i made some changes to the answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using `Ext.Msg.alert` or `Ext.Msg.confirm` or `Ext.Msg.show` method you can apply following style to change button color

```
.x-msgbox .x-button {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color : red !important; // red will be the button color
}
```

Comment: Some other style was overriding it.  .x-button, .x-toolbar .x-button{
background: none;
background-image:none;
}  Setting and then setting what you gave worked. But i don't want to mention the class for each and every alert i have. Is there any generalised method?

Comment: ya, thats why i given !important; to style.. see my answer

Comment: Can it be more generalised without giving cls to all alert boxes?

Comment: are you asking without applying css you want to differentiate button color in alert box?

Comment: My alert box is like this : Ext.Msg.alert('title','Message clear_session',function(){
      console.log('method defn');
       });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31915/discussion-between-akshatha-and-viswa)